# LINQ to MySQL join query on dag

Tags: mysql, sql, linq, left-join

I have a dag structure defined in the following 2 tables:

```
TABLE: ORGANISATION
--------------------------------------------
|           |                               |
|   ID      |   Guid            NOT NULL    |
|   Name    |   varchar(200)    NOT NULL    |
|   IsTop   |   bool            NOT NULL    |
|           |                               |
---------------------------------------------

TABLE: EDGE
--------------------------------------------
|           |                               |
|   ID      |   Guid            NOT NULL    |
|   From    |   Guid            NOT NULL    |
|   To      |   Guid            NOT NULL    |
|           |                               |
---------------------------------------------
```

Using **LINQ**, is it possible to pick all ORGANISATIONs where (IsTop == true **OR** there is no EDGE with To field that points to the ID of ORGANISATION) **using a single query**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know if this will help you but

```
var query = from org in ORGANISATION
                       where org.IsTop == "true" ||
                        !(FROM ed in EDGE
                       select ed.To).CONTAINS(org.ID)
                       select org;
```